# Take centroid of multipolygons and use it as center of a circle

Tags: qgis, postgis, postgresql

I'm working with QGIS (or rather discovering QGIS, should I say) and I have a data structure that looks like this:

```
PLACE_NAME      ST_ASTEXT(geom)
     x        MULTIPOLYGON1(...)
     x        MULTIPOLYGON2(...)
     y        MULTIPOLYGON3(...)
     y        MULTIPOLYGON4(...)
     y        MULTIPOLYGON5(...)
     x        MULTIPOLYGON6(...)
    ...              ...
```

For a certain place (say "x"), I would like to compute the centroid of all its multipolygons taken as a whole. Then, I need to use this centroid to find all the multipolygons that are located within a circle whose center is the above-mentioned centroid and whose radius is 10 kilometers. In a mix of pseudo SQL and personal code, this looks like this:

```
SELECT centroid(average(geom)) as UComP -- Unique Centroid of my Polygons
FROM my_table
WHERE PLACE_NAME = 'x'
```

And then:

```
SELECT *
FROM my_table
WHERE ST_Within(geom, ST_Transform(ST_Buffer(ST_Transform(ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(ST_X(UComP), ST_Y(UComP)), 4326), 3857), 10000), 4326)) = true)
```

Unfortunately, I'm facing some problems with the beginning, i.e. the calculation of the centroid. It seems that PostGIS doesn't really like the average function called on a geometry.

In addition to a solution to the above problem, I'd ideally need a unique query instead of two distinct ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly the following query should return the rows that you want.

```
SELECT *
FROM my_table
WHERE ST_DWithin( -- returns true if geoms are with n distance of each other
    ST_SetSRID(geom::Geography,4326), -- the table geometries
    (SELECT ST_SetSRID(ST_Centroid(ST_Collect(geom::Geometry))::Geography,4326) -- Geometric centroid for the collection of geoms
     FROM my_table 
     WHERE place_name = 'X'), -- Centroid of place name
    10000 -- Distance
    );
```

This use [ST_Collect](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_Collect.html) to aggregate the geometries and [ST_Centroid](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_Centroid.html) to calculate the geometric center of the collection.  [ST_Dwithin](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_DWithin.html) is then used to filter the rows to those with a geometry with 10,000 metres of the centroid.

This query has been written to handle geometries that contain WGS84 features.

If you want the geometries to be wholly within the circle you may need to create a buffer around the centroid and use [ST_Contains](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_Contains.html) or [ST_Within](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_Within.html)

Comment: I indeed have a lat/long geometry (4326). I tried to adapt your solution by using ST_Transform (into geom 3857) and ST_SetSRID, but there must be something that I don't understand because I always get 0 row. To be more precise, I tested all sorts of combinations inside the inner query, such as: SELECT ST_Transform(ST_Centroid(ST_Collect(geom)), 3857) or SELECT ST_Centroid(ST_Transform(ST_Collect(geom), 3857)) and so forth. Can you help me out? :)

Comment: @Guillaume I have altered the query to deal with WGS84 lat/longs

Answer (score 0):

I think u can first create the table of your **places centroïds** with something like :

```
create table places_centroids as
select st_centroid(st_union(p.geometry)),p.place_id,p.place_name from "places" p
group by place_name
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I however get the following error message when trying to run your code:  *GEOSUnaryUnion: TopologyException: found non-noded intersection between LINESTRING (5.95225 47.2283, 5.95225 47.2283) and LINESTRING (5.95225 47.2283, 5.95225 47.2283) at 5.9522477841036423 47.228260348101763*

Comment: I don't think the problem is in the query but rather **in your source data**. There's obviously some topology error(s) in your data. U can go straight do these coordinates to try to solve the error 'manually' but if there are many other that can surely be a bit painful ...